# Smart URL Synchronization/Download Engine available open source?

Tags: perl, url, synchronization, programming-languages

I am wondering if anybody is aware of an open-source URL Synchronization/Download engine or if I will end up writing my own one.

Expected functionality:
- Provide a plain list of HTTP Urls to be synchronized on a local disk store
- Engine takes care of synchronizing URL content as effectively (HEAD request to check for changes) and efficiently (all download performed using Gzip compression)
- Preferably it would be smart enough to optimize its beahvior by recognizing URLs that change frequently

Is someone aware of an alike-implementation of such engine? Preferably in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [lwp-mirror](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-mirror) program that comes with LWP? That might be a good place to start. Alternatively, [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) has more features.